# How can I get socket.io to work with subdomains?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm running a node application that conditionally `.use`s other applications based on the subdomain of the HTTP request. The code for that is as below:

```
var server = http.createServer(app);
```

...

```
global.socket = io.listen(server);
```

...

```
subdomains.forEach(function (subdomain) {
    var vhost = (subdomain == '_' ? '' : subdomain + '.') + domain;
    app.use(express.vhost(vhost, require('./' + subdomain)));
});
```

Now suppose I want to use socket.io in two different subdomains. They both have access to the same socket, since it's running on the same port. Yet if I try to connect to `http://sub1.domain.tld/`, any broadcasts are also sent to `http://sub2.domain.tld/`.

Is there any way I can restrict broadcast, emit, &c. based on the subdomain of the connection?

Comment: No, if your process is listening on that port, the data will be received by your process.  You could ignore data coming into a connection based on the url queried, or better yet, set up a proxy service on your main port, and two different services on different ports for your respective servers.  Then proxy the requests, based on which subdomain is pinged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to mark as "answered". As of now, it appears that there is no way to accomplish what I'm trying to do.